# Laravel 5.2 $errors not appearing in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm following along with the Laravel 5 fundamentals tutorial and I am stuck on the form validation. I have followed along exactly with the tutorial but I am getting a Undefined variable: errors in my create articles view.

In the tutorial I am following and what I have found online they say the errors variable is always there in the blade file for you to use so I don't know what i am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated! loving Laravel except for this error!

```
View
    @if($errors->any())
      <ul class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach($errors->any() as $error)
          <li>{{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    @endif
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest as UserRequest;
// use App\Http\Requests\CreateArticleRequest as CreateArticleRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ErrorBinder;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
      return view('pages.signUp');
    }

    public function store(UserRequest $request){
      User::create($request->all());
      return 'the user has been registered!';
      return view('user.profile');
    }

}
```

Request validation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'country' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
            'height' => 'required',
            'weight' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the validation.

Comment: Neal please post your controller thats calling this view and your validation logic. Will make it a lot easier for people to help you :)

Answer (score 41):

This is a breaking problem with the 5.2 upgrade.  What's happening is the middleware which is responsible for making that `errors` variable available to all your views is not being utilized because it was moved from the global middleware to the `web` middleware group.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. In your `kernel.php` file, you can move the middleware `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` back to the `protected $middleware` property.
2. You can wrap all your web routes with a route group and apply the `web` middleware to them.

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
       // Place all your web routes here...
   });
   ```

Comment: This is getting me most of the way there Thank you so much! It's been driving me crazy since yesterday! 
now I can see the error UL tag appear.. but the error messages aren't actually filling up? 

I went with the Route Option you suggested

Comment: And it's fully fixed now! 
put all of my routes that required validation into the route group you suggested and the foreach in my view need $errors->all()

Thank you so much!

Comment: What did you need to do to get the errors variable to fill up so I can modify the answer?

Comment: I'm following the [Intermediate Tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate) and having this problem with **ALL** the auth routes. The instructions in that page are incorrect (or perhaps incompleted). The best solution to the problem is #2 above.

Comment: `Route::auth()` is actually by default called in a `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web']`... so this just suggests doing the default... which doesn't actually seem to want to help..?

Comment: Thanks for this post.  I already did option 2, but decided to do the opposite and move my route out of the middleware, and then it worked.  I decided to follow the advice below and make the needed changes to my Kernel.php file.

Answer (score 24):

**Solved**

You may change any one of the following:

**1. put your working route `(app/http/routes.php)` on**

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Here like
    Route::get('/', 'TodoController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'TodoController@store');
});`

Screenshot -

[image: Screendshot 1]

**2. Move your `protected $middlewareGroups web` `(app/Http/Kernel.php)` on `protected $middleware = []`**

Screenshot -

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me.  Why aren't the middlewareGroups needed for validation in the kernel available by default?

Comment: This works for me. Btw, I didnt like option of moving middleware group to global but I wanted to add two middleware for admin url. "web" and "admin". As they say, web is automatically add by routeserviceprovider so If I add only admin then it doesnt take any other middleware assigned for web so I have to give both option like Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','admin'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () { ... and this doesnt work as web included two times. Laravel team should fix this asap;

Comment: sweet thats what wecall an answer :)

Comment: Superb....... it's working perfect for me..... you save my lot's of time

Answer (score 19):

This is solution:

Change the defination of your Route groups with a **middleware**, **from** :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
```

to

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => 'web'], function () {
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13000

Comment: None of the above worked for me (except modify the Kernel.php file, but I don't like this solutions for many stuff), but this solution fix my problem.   I have many nested Route:group in my routes.php file and I am using Route:resource too

Comment: Here and now in 2017, this is the solution to this problem. Thanks a lot @Yuri

Answer (score 18):

simply, you have to move :

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

from `protected $middlewareGroups` to `protected $middleware`

Answer (score 7):

1. Just remove `, 'middleware' => 'web'` from `Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'web'), function()` in ***routes.php*** page   OR
2. Move

   `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,`

From `protected $middlewareGroups` to `protected $middleware` in ***kernel.php*** page

As the Laravel Documentation says:

> Note: If your copy of Laravel has a RouteServiceProvider that already
>   includes the default routes file within the web middleware group, you
>   do not need to manually add the group to your routes.php file.

So removing from `routes.php` file would be the correct way.

Answer (score 5):

Posting this as it might be useful for others,

As Smartrahat mentioned in 1st solution, in your `Kernel.php` file(`app/Http/Kernel.php`) move `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class`
from `$middlewareGroups` to `protected $middleware` property, but the same will start throwing the error "Session store not set on request",

to resolve this move
`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` to `$middleware property` as well.

Answer (score 4):

As of 5.2, `routes.php` is by default already called in the context of a `['middleware'=>'web']` by `RouteServiceProvider`. But in `routes.php` default generation of auth routes, the `Route::group` call is still happening by default - so if you delete that `Route::group` declaration from `routes.php` the application then correctly shows errors.

Comment: Seems like you're right, and this would explains: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12022

Comment: This has now been fixed in the latest checkouts. The middleware is gone from the routes and all works again.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of observations regarding this issue. First off there a related bug in github regarding this issue
PFA
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12022

If you look at the last comment which Graham wrote, I think that is the facing I was facing.
For me even though there was a error in form post data, I was getting the below equality

```
boolval(count($errors) === 0) === true
```

In my case I added log statements in the

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

the above  middleware class ran twice for a given request, I am not sure why it ran twice, but I think because of this the `$errors` variable is getting reset.
I was using this configuration (which I think came default with Laravel@5.2.43)

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

I changed the configuration which worked for me and the `$errors` variable's count is not zero (also the above middleware ran only once per request)

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

Note:
All my routes are in the `web` middleware group before and after the Kernel.php configuration change, I didnot move my routes at all from the `web` middleware group.

Answer (score 2):

Change `@foreach($errors->any() as $error)` to `@foreach($errors->all() as $error)`

Comment: Still getting the same error Undefined variable: errors

And i am now following the docs with regards to the form validation linked here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Answer (score 0):

in this case **laravel 5.2** you can refer may example code and edit your `kernal.php` file. move this  `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class`, form `middlewareGroups` to `middleware` and add  `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class`, to  `middleware` 
then its work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Having both Web and API requirements in our application, we did not want to move the middleware around; perhaps that would have worked, however:

We had the very peculiar situation that the `flash[]` and `$errors` session data was transmitted correctly between the standard laravel resource methods, `store()` and `edit()`, but in some cases the data did not get back across nearly identical methods, `storeSale()` and `editSale()`.

We found that in our development and deployment environments, the 'file' and 'database' session drivers worked in all cases, but the 'cookie' driver did not.

Switching to the database driver in all instances solved the problem.