# Using $errors in blade template in Lumen

Tags: php, lumen

I have a simple piece of code that I would like to use inside the blade template:

```
@if($errors->has())
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <div>{{ $error }}</div>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

However in order to use $errors, I read somewhere that I need to use `web` middleware so I set that as well for the route:

```
'middleware' => ['web']
```

and added:

```
$app->register(Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class);
$app->register(Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class);
```

to the app.php

But now, when I open this route, I'm getting this error:

```
lumen.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Session\SessionManager, instance of Laravel\Lumen\Application given
```

Comment: Are you using laravel 5.2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438463/laravel-5-2-errors-not-appearing-in-blade

Comment: It is 5.1.I tried to follow some of the answers from the linked thread, it seems that the error is gone, but I'm getting now  `exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: errors'` when I try to access $error in the view, it's like middleware is not included at all.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add this to app.php:

```
$app->middleware([ 
             Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,                        
             Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
]);
```