# Can't get $error variable in blade template Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, error-handling, laravel-5

I am trying to show $errors on `Form`  request, but is not displaying. Although, my `routes` are under `web` middleware.

Here is my code in `view`.

```
    @if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

In Routes

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function () {
       Route::get('admin/add/user',[ 'as' => 'addUser', 'uses' =>'UserController@addUser']);
    });
```

I don't know where I getting wrong. Any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438463/laravel-5-2-errors-not-appearing-in-blade

Comment: My routes are already in `web` middleware, as said in your provided link

Comment: Have you defined ->withErrors() in your controller?

Comment: What version of 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{!! $error !!}` instead of `{{ $error }}`