# error with auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I am build a Laravel e-commerce site and I seem to be having difficulty with the login page. When I run /auth/login I get the following error message:

> ErrorException in 331b09d5d399f256b356d4ae58180ae01edf5c37.php line 12: Undefined variable: errors (View: /home/thomas/ushop/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)

```
in 331b09d5d399f256b356d4ae58180ae01edf5c37.php line 12
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/thomas/ushop/storage/framework/views/331b09d5d399f256b356d4ae58180ae01edf5c37.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/home/thomas/ushop/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application))) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 199
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1087
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24
at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RedirectIfAuthenticated), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AuthController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getLogin') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController', 'getLogin') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_userm(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

This puzzles me because I'm using the user system that comes with Laravel right out of the box. Is it possible it's because no form errors were created yet?

EDIT here's my code:

```
    @extends('vendor.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i>Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

EDIT2: My controller code, though this came straight out of the box with Laravel since it shipped by default

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `line 12: Undefined variable: errors (View: /home/thomas/ushop/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)` - Have a look there

Comment: I am still coming to framework development over from procedural PHP programming. Thanks/

Comment: It's hard to know what is broken down without code, please post your code

Comment: your controller code, you're not setting your errors variable to the view

Comment: `$errors` is available throughout the application if you use the `SessionMiddleware`. Adding your routes to the `web` group or using `SessionMiddleware` in your controller (by adding it in the `__construct()` method). [Definitely check this question and its answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34900644/867418)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 $errors not appearing in Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438463/laravel-5-2-errors-not-appearing-in-blade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused because you're not setting the `errors` variable to your view, at your controller you must

```
 return view('auth', ['errors' => $erros]);
```