# Validation messages aren't showed on the view in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have `ItemController.php` and `ItemRequest.php.`. `ItemController.php` is responsible for adding items and `ItemRequest.php` for form validation.

In `ItemRequest.php` I have this rules

```
class ItemRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'title.required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
            'category_id.requred' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
        ];
    }
}
```

In my view I have this

```
@if($errors->has())
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
               {{ $error }}</br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

The problem is that the form doesn't get any validation. I'm able to click Submit with empty fields and they are inserted in DB.

and this is the store function from `ItemController.php`

```
public function store( ItemRequest $request )
{      
    $item = new Item;
    $item->title = $request['title'];
    if( empty( $request['alias']) ) {
      $request['alias'] = $request['title'];
    }
    $item->category_id = $request['category_id'];
    $item->save();
    return redirect()->route('admin.items');
}
```

Why I don't get any messages or validation on the page?

Comment: Where is the $errors variable defined in your code?

Comment: Do you define a validator function in `ItemController.php`?

Comment: No, I'm not defined this in ItemController

Comment: How did you create `ItemRequest` is it with the command line ?

Comment: @Maraboc, no was manually. I even tried to add the validation directly in the function instead of separate file and still no messages.

Comment: Which Request is `ItemRequest` extending? `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` or `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Comment: Check your URL and routes. Is you in correct page? error message will show only in form page.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, `namespace App\Http\Requests; use App\Http\Requests\Request;` this

Comment: @DinukaThilanga, it doesn't change the page after submitting the form with invalid inputs. It's just refreshing the page and I must see the errors but I don't. So, the error messages are added to this view blade,

Comment: Check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438463/laravel-5-2-errors-not-appearing-in-blade

Answer (score 0):

`$request` is an object, not an array.
Your code should look like this

```
$item = new Item;
$item->title = $request->get('title');
if( $request->has('alias') ) {
    // ??? 
    $request['alias'] = $request['title'];
}
$item->category_id = $request->get('category_id');
$item->save();
return redirect()->route('admin.items');
```

You can also use `$request->has('name')` to check if a field has been submitted. But i am not sure what are you trying to do in the if statement.

Comment: Still nothing on the page. Doesn't show any messages for error.

Comment: But does it add something in the db?

Comment: Nope. Nothing is inserted

Comment: Then validation works, there is something wrong in the view where the errors are shown. Remove the if statement and let it print all.

Comment: Removed the if but I see only `Whoops! There were some problems with your input.` and nothing from the foreach

Comment: $request implements array access

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a validator function in `ItemController` that validates `ItemRequest` using the rules you so defined.

```
protected function validator($data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, app(ItemRequest::class)->rules());
}
```

[The Illuminate\Http\Foundation\FormRequest handles a failedValidation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L115) redirecting back to the previous URL with the errorBag available in the session for the view.

This isn't something [Illuminate\Http\Request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php) handles for you.

In `ItemController` write a `validate` method, and use this as a precondition in `store` before doing work.

```
function validate(Request $request) {
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
}

function store(ItemRequest $request) {
    $this->validate($request);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added this to itemcontroller but still nothing on page

Comment: You need to extend FormRequest and not Request. Otherwise, you'll need to implement a bunch of methods to ensure a failed validation is handled correctly.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to `class ItemRequest extends FormRequest` no messages again. Do I need to make so other change?

Comment: Yeah, you need to call the validator to check the request and raise the necessary exception. If you don't still get the error messages in the view, you may need to consider the question @DinukaThilanga linked to in your question

Comment: Still empty. `var_dump($errors)` return `object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#247 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(0) { } }`. It can't be so complex to add some validations

Comment: This fixed the issue. I don't understand why this happen and why this is not fixed. As I understand this is issue(?) from version 5.2... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900644/8323337