# Laravel 5.4 $error not showing/flashed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a fresh installation of Laravel 5.4 using vagrant for windows.

Now as I followed through the tuts in laracast and tried the form validation it was all fine but the **$errors** variable just doesn't contain any error messages at all.

snippet is from **PostsController**

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts,title|min:3',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    Post::firstOrCreate(request(['title', 'body']));

    return redirect()->route('create-post');
}
```

snippet from my **create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8 blog-main">
            <h3 class="pb-3 mb-4 font-italic border-bottom">
                Create Post Form
            </h3>


            <form action="/api/posts" method="POST">

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title" value="">
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="body">Content</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="body" rows="5" name="body" placeholder="Contents Here.." value=""></textarea>
                    <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('body') }}</small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="alert alert-{{ $errors->any() ? 'danger' : 'default' }}">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

        @include('partials.sidebar')

    </div>

</main>
@endsection
```

and the result after validation failed

[image: errors_no_showing]

Is there something that I am missing or somethings wrong?

**Edit**

here's the snippet of my **route**:

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');

Route::get('/create', function() {
   return view('posts.create');
})->name('create-post');

Route::post('/posts', 'PostsController@store');
```

Comment: alert-danger class exist? or you made it or not??

Comment: What are you expecting to be present in '$errors'?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson, I am expecting it to show some errors like 

title is required

Comment: Is 'create.blade.php' what is routed to with "redirect()->route('create-post')"? If so, can we see the view/form the user is accessing the 'store' action method with?

Comment: i think laravel automatically redirects back once the validation fails, in this case the /create or (create-post) also I've updated and included the route snippet @ryanwebjackson

Comment: OK, but you have to be accessing /posts from either JavaScript or an HTML link. Where is that?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson ahh yes, ill update the post.blade

Comment: @ryanwebjackson the (/posts) is being called in the form in create.blade.php

Comment: @xkrlaix alert-danger class is from bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Since that it's 5.4 I didnt notice that all the web.php was under a middleware called **web**

that that includes with it the ***\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class***

my **api/posts** was on the **api** middleware thats why there's no session shared whatsoever.

also this link helped solved this.

[Laravel 5.2 $errors not appearing in Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438463/laravel-5-2-errors-not-appearing-in-blade)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `Request` object in the validator. You need to change the validation code a bit:

```
$this->validate(request()->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts,title|min:3',
    'body' => 'required'
]);
```

Read more in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-creating-the-controller).

Comment: $this->validate first param must be an instance of Request object not an array

Answer (score 0):

You can validate this way
 `$this->validate($request, [
          'title' => 'required|unique:posts,title|min:3',
          'body' => 'required'
        ]);`

I hope this will work.